# Chrome 25 and iScroll functionality broken

Tags: google-chrome, iscroll

In the new beta Chrome 25 there is broken functionality of commonly used javascript library iScroll(4). The current version 24 works well. Any mouse event problem or something like this?

http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/

Comment: This is a workaround. Disable the touch events in chrome: Set **Enable touch events** under _chrome://flags/_ to disabled.

Answer (score 0):

See also bug report on [github](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/343)

Bad thing is: I have one device where ist doesn't work, and multiples where it works! Chrome version is absolute identically.